# Cron дописывать в лог файл, а не переписывать его

Tags: cron

Есть скрипт на python, поставил задачу в cron выполнять его 1 раз в день.

```
14  02  *   *   *     cd /home/user/project/tools/ && ./script.py > /home/user/project/logs/log_script
```

Проверяю лог файл и обнаруживаю что каждый день лог новый, то есть вчерашние данные затираются новыми.

Подскажите как настроить чтобы дописывало в файл, а не перетирало его каждый день?
Ну и совсем фантастика если бы дописывало в начало файла, а не в конец.

Comment: замените `>` на `>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

но если сильно хочется именно в начало, то можно где то так

```
cd /home/user/project/tools/ && ./script.py > ../logs/log_script_t && cat ../logs/log_script >> ../logs/log_script_t && rm ../logs/log_script && mv ../logs/log_script_t ../logs/log_script
```

построчно

выведем в временный файл

```
cd /home/user/project/tools/ && ./script.py > ../logs/log_script_t
```

а теперь в него допишем содержимое лога.

```
&& cat ../logs/log_script >> ../logs/log_script_t
```

удалим файл с логом

```
&& rm ../logs/log_script
```

и переименуем временный файл

```
&& mv ../logs/log_script_t ../logs/log_script
```

Comment: Или так

    cd /home/user/project/tools/ && ./script.py > ../logs/log_script_$$ && touch ../logs/log_script && cat ../logs/log_script >> ../logs/log_script_$$ && mv -f ../logs/log_script_$$ ../logs/log_script


`touch` нужен, если `../logs/log_script` еще не создан, а `$$` в `../logs/log_script_$$` позволит нескольким скриптам работать до некоторй степени одновременно.

Answer (score 2):

```
> заменить на >>
```

Для помещения лога в начало потребуется некоторое количество переменных, магии, cat и echo, здесь я помочь не могу, но вряд ли эта конструкция адекватно влезет в строчку.